# Plug for Area 51 proposal

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

I'd like to plug an [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications?referrer=ExEBrFiJfIFCxT7Iq4t4JA2) that might be relevant for many game developers.  What's the best way for me to do that on [Game Dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)?  It seems odd to make that into a question somehow.  Even if I did form a question out of it, selecting an answer seems like a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way would be to create a [Community Promotion Ad](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/community-promotion-ads-2h-2011)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I posted the promotion there.  Hopefully, it'll get some hits.