# Advertising free (as in freedom) projects on Game Development

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**What is the policy for advertising your free (as in "free software" not as in "freeware") own projects on Gave Development?** Is that welcome?

If yes, are there any guidelines one should abide by?

The rationale behind my question is that:

- For the game author it would be a great way to **get feedback** from fellow game programmers
- For fellow game programmers, it would be a great way to have **working example code** to analyse / modify / build on
- Although advertising a game is not technically a "question", **the upvote/downvote feature on both the ad and the "answers" to it, would be a terrific tool for peer reviewing the project**, helping developers new to the game industry to spot and prioritise possible issues.

PS: I notice the [Community Promotion Ads](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/456/8275) question, but if I understood it right, that initiative focuses only on getting an ad banner "out there", rather than at collecting feedback on projects.

Comment: There is also a chat, if there is anything you want to talk about which isnt exactly a question, check it out. As long as its related to game progamming and you dont spam people there with pure advertising, great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you're meaning 'Can I put my game on here to be reviewed codewise and peer-checked?'

This really isn't the place. For one thing, it can be subjective (I don't like X because Y, though someone else might like X because of Z). Secondly, it's a lot of code slogging and is almost lazy; 'here's 10K lines of code, look through it and tell me what you think'.

There also isn't really a question. If you're meaning 'How could I improve this code', you'd provide a snippet, not a huge project.

Comment: You got me right, and I totally see your point (+1). On the other hand - as per the _community promotion ads_ - it could be a specific tag which could not necessarily enforce the "objectivity rule". One would know what question tagged "project-notice" are, and would check them out only if interested... My thinking is that it would be useful to leverage the GD community expertise in this case too. Anyhow... my question is tagged "discussion" exactly because I am not 100% sure myself this would work as expected, so thank you for chipping in! :)

Comment: Tags are there to categorize questions, not to separate questions from non-questions. Community promotion ads are different because they don't mix with the questions - they are off to the side, where one would expect an ad, and they are obviously an ad and not a question.

Comment: Tags are also to be used to cover the *content* of the question.  Not the *kind* of question.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is an appropriate place or format for that kind of thing.

Now you can use your game/library as the source to an answer, for example if your library implements a particular feature and there's a relevant question you can use your project as an reference as long as you state your affiliation with said project.

As far as the Community Promotion Ads, whenever you hover over a banner it does provide a link to the answer in the question, where comments could be left.  It's not what you're looking for, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Would you mind to articulate a bit more on why you don't think it's the "appropriate place"? Beside the "rule" I would be interested to understand the "thinking" behind the rule. :)

Comment: As our FAQ states, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." And as you said, "advertising a game is not technically a 'question'". There are other game development places (e.g. forums) which are open to hearing about your projects and giving feedback. And there is of course the entire public, if you release your project and advertise it (e.g. via the ads); you can always collect feedback on the project website or built-in to the project itself. This site, however, is focused on questions and answers.

Comment: @mac: This is a Q&A site, not an advertisement community. We're here to help others get their questions answered. Anything more than that is beyond the scope of this place.