# Advertisements about proposals that are already in Beta

Tags: discussion

I have realised that the advertisements about new proposals shown in the right sidebar of gamedev.stackexchange.com are not always updated to their current progress. I initially thought that this was an "acceptable" issue. However, today there is still an advertisement about the new 3D graphics stackexchange site saying that its current state is "52% commited", which is totally wrong since the site is [online already](http://cgi.stackexchange.com/).

This can be a bit misleading to some users, and it is maybe even a "waste" of advertisement space. (to advertise a proposal that already exists...).

Is there any way to fix this? Is this happening also to other stackexchange sites?

[image]

Comment: The proposal ads should never be cached for more than an hour.  All the other ones I've seen look fine.  I've passed it along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that this banner is not from the Area51 site, but rather a community-promotion-ad!

<strike>See here: [Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/community-promotion-ads-2h-2011)</strike>

That's also why the percentage never changed there...

**Update:** The Ad has been removed from the linked thread.