# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/983/community-promotion-ads-2013)

We're hitting the next milestone, and so we begin anew with our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool game development related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/675).

Comment: Am I allowed to post links to my own content? For example, I made a tutorial for my engine, which is hosted on my blog, is it OK if I post a link (image) to my blog? Or, should I post it as a link to the tutorial itself?

Comment: @Bane If people vote on it, it will be okay. You may be better off adverting the tutorial if that is the main item you'd like to advert, though.

Comment: Great, I'll post it once I get home.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Visit the new Chess Stack Exchange site]

Answer (score 5):

[image: CompoHub, a little site that lists all kinds of game development events that are available all around the world.]

Answer (score -2):

[image: A tutorial on how to use my HTML5 game engine, Irenic.]