# A non-question acceptable as post?

Tags: discussion

Seeing how Stanford University is offering their Game Theory course online for free, I figured that the place to post it on would be gamedev.SE, but I'm unsure if that's okay or not. Is it?

For those interested, the course starts Monday next week (March 19th), and you can find it here: http://www.gametheory-class.org/

Comment: No.

But you could probably add it here:

http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/675/community-promotion-ads-2012

Comment: Making an announcement in chat and/or on meta (@Tetrad, sanity check me on this? :)) would be fine, but it's definitely not appropriate for the main site.

Comment: I agree that an announcement here on Meta would be allowed - at least, when I [asked about an Announcement tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101606/can-we-get-an-announcement-required-tag-for-secondary-meta-sites), the answer was that the `discussion + featured` tags were sufficient. Which implied that it is also *allowed* to have announcements on secondary meta sites. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would not be acceptable on gamedev.stackexchange. The site is for asking (and answering) specific questions related to game development as defined [in the FAQ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq).

Posting it here on meta would be more acceptable, especially as an answer to [this question Tetrad linked to in his comment](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/community-promotion-ads-2012).

The most acceptable place, I think, would be [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development).