# Why is an advertisement for a closed beta site showing up?

Tags: support, status-completed

[image]

I wasn't sure where this should be brought up,  so here it is, probably something that a developer should look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the post from the [community ads](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/983/community-promotion-ads-2013) thread that I believe to be responsible for the ad appearing, so it should no longer appear.

Comment: is there any way that `Joe User` can do that or is that strictly a moderator privilege?

Comment: @Malachi You can vote down the ad. Only ads with (I think?) 6+ votes will be displayed on the sidebar.

Comment: I apologize, but where are these posted? link please.

Comment: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/983/community-promotion-ads-2013